# TeamCity Professional 10.0.3 (build 42434) Visual studio 2013 solution error :Unmet requirements: MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path exists

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, teamcity

I am new to TeamCity and difficulties building  Visual studio 2013 soln testing on win 7 .My Plan is to make TeamCity automate build & deployment on committing to svn server with 2 builds.  1-Build -> Build xyz.sln file  with 2  web application projects -> proj1 & proj2 . 2-Publish -> If 1-Build is Successful then publish  proj2 web application project to test & prod server (2 servers). I did the setup of svn trunk on TeamCity which has xyz.soln file and connection tested successfully. When I tried to build the configuration with my xyz.soln 
Build Step :[image]

When I tried to run the build it was giving: Warning: No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration. Please register a build agent or tweak build configuration requirements.
[image]

Followed this -> http://www.danmusk.com/how-to-build-asp-net-applications-in-teamcity-with-msbuild-tools-2013-and-net-framework-4-5-sdk/
Installed  MSBuild separately and confirmed 
MSBuild Tools 2013 -> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin
 also .Net framework -> [image]

windows SDK ->

[image]

https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206843275-Unmet-requirements-MSBuildTools12-0-x86-Path-exists
[image]

Any help would be great? Need to fix this Issue badly .

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the appropriate MSBuild Tools, you likely just need to restart the build agent so it can re-register with the current set of capabilities.

To illustrate how this works, you can first look at the Build Configuration's Agent Requirements:
[image: TeamCity Agent Requirements]

In this example, you can see the build needs MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path defined (as well as some .NET framework stuff).

Over on the Agent's parameters, under Agents->[Agent1]->Agent Parameters->Configuration Parameters, you can see a list like this:
[image: Team City Agent Config Parameters]

In my case, the value is present so it's considered a 'compatible agent'.

How do these settings get on the agent? Well, when the agent starts up it checks all these things to see what it's capable of and includes them in this big list of Configuration Parameters.

Therefore, if you install something like MSBuild Tools, you'll need to restart the agent... it runs as a service, so just go to the services panel on the agent box and restart it.

Comment: I installed MSBuild Tools 2013  on my machine -> https://p7.zdusercontent.com/attachment/787891/HhtVJibDCOOYeUytaNvkIbSSb?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..BhdgQaf5BvQZESWhnT6HWw.44Uth13VHmge8J3Yq_NEGopR9cIuILPBwqjxzkE6EoQDZXXMT8yOtXe1K1-pi74JHpnRNCbwljfIixxlJxIxEN8jrUoskSqIKqzRqfHv1DKgfayyCrvfyoidLnJIEQCp25tl9SnohACwXFlcgE4MR952Cr81AhwMBFkjT-yxjjyCwyK2TcOGddnxOylHcv5fhgLbJUcTe3TXxqV3WUWZmExYmkBh9yH_Bj5XD3asWIFYvnMV5L7VQ-Mm25OpLPL5a4ZnAvw01zXq7QYiKqusTg.vxfObgT8GIKgzEgTtmPErA

Comment: I know it's been 8 days since you asked, but did you restart the agent? It runs as a windows service on the box. It won't indicate changes in the environment until the service is restarted.

Comment: If you look at the Agent->Agent Parameters->Configuration Parameters, it should list entries under MSBuildTools12.0_x64_Path and MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path, but again... only after restarting the agent service. These are the two config entries your build process is expecting that it's not finding (you can see this under the build configuration's Agent Requirements settings)

Comment: Hi Brett Green. Thanks for the advise. I am off until 3rd January and will update on 3rd Jan.

Comment: Hi Brett,  I can't see any entries for MSBuild Tools Under Agent->Agent Parameters->Configuration Parameters after restarting the agent service.  I try to uninstall the MsBuildTools &  install it again. ( Agent Config Parmeter edited in my original post)

Comment: You can certainly manually add these params to the agent's configuration file (buildagent.properties) under the conf folder. This will get you building and you can come back later to figure why it won't register properly. There's a way to enable debugging logs on the agent as well that may help.

Comment: Hi Brett, Thanks for the advise.  I will give a try to fix the Issue. I can build the solutions  using command line --> Runner Type: CommandLine, Run:Executable with parameters,CommandExecutable: C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild \12.0 \Bin\ MsBuild.exe,Command parameters: %SolutionFileWithPath%